# Passing a JSON object from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I generate a json object inside my php file using json_encode but when I parse it in Javascript I get error unknow token which is because when I print the returned string it is actually html code not a json string.

let's consider the simplest case:

php:

```
 $testjson = '{"result":true,"count":1}';
 echo $testjson;
```

js:

```
$.get("serverside.php", function(data, status) {
                      JSON.parse(data); // I get error here
                });
```

how should I use that JSON object from php  in javascript?

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add what "html code" is? i.e. output of `console.log(data)` instead of `JSON.parse(data)`. Also, there is a convenience method `$.getJSON`, that will skip a few steps.

Comment: When I test this jquery and php on my server it seems to work.  What error are you seeing?

Comment: Your provided sample code is correct, Provide the original code , if server is already sending data as json not as string then JSON.parse will give error.

Comment: I think I had an error somewhere else in the php file and therefore an error kind of html was passed to Javascript instead. It works for me now as well! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It probably best you create your json array a bit more dynamically in php :

```
$testjson = array();
$testjson['result'] = true;
$testjson['count'] = 1;
echo json_encode($testjson);
```

Answer (score 0):

What Tanantos said is you best bet. I personally would've write it like:

```
$testjson = array(
    "result" => true,
    "count"  => 1
);
echo json_encode($testjson);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP :

```
$testjson = array(
    "result" => true,
    "count"  => 1
);
echo json_encode($testjson);
```

js :

```
$.get('serverside.php', function(json){
    console.log(json); 
}, 'json');
```

- jquery-1.10.2.min